# Error on import of mysqldump file - Illegal double value found during parsing

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump, import

I am currently getting the following error while trying to import / restore a mysqldump file:

```
ERROR 1367 (22007) at line 445: Illegal double '1.79769313486232e+308' 
value found during parsing
```

I looked at various places online and could not find anything that was similar.

**Some background:**

I am trying to create a new replication box and the mysqldump is new from another replica box. Both boxes are:

> CentOS 5.7 with MySQL 5.0.77-4

Used the following to create the mysqldump:

```
$ mysqldump --lock-all-tables --all-databases | gzip -9 > mysqldump.sql.gz
```

The new replication box has nothing on there right now and all the databases / tables are supposed to be created by mysqldump. Any insights?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[**There is current open bug report on this one**](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=44995).

The bug report has a suggested work around at the bottom entry [22 Jan 2010 6:46]:

`replace 1.79769313486232e+308 \'1.79769313486232e+308\' -- filename`

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: nice find, Rolando!

Comment: that helped, thanx a lot!!

Answer (score -1):

sed -i "s/1.79769313486232e+308/'1.79769313486232e+308'/g" mysqlDump.sql